# Is it OK to use Monitor.TryEnter in event handler method?

Tags: c#, event-handling, locking

I have EventHandler method which is called pretty often and it's body processing takes some time. Is it OK, to lock operations inside this handler it via Monitor? 
The purpose is that meanwhile locker locks the object other events and processing of the object are simply skipped.

```
public void MyEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
if (!Monitor.TryEnter(locker)) return; // skipping meanwhile processing

// do some stuff here

Monitor.Exit(locker)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

it looks like it would be cleaner/more performant to

- (a) prevent the events from being raised
- (b) use a condition variable.

Regardless, always put the Monitor.Exit into a finally block

Comment: +1 for finally block. But if there are resource or other thing that can be accessed by more than one event handlers?

Comment: ad (a) prevent the events from being raised:
Preventing fireing event method is not possible directly, because eventhandler is called from proprietary DLL. 
@TheVillageIdiot: well, there are some resources which can be accessed but only for reading.

Answer (score 1):

It's not horrible, as long as:

- You're doing this on a background thread (or, to the point, you're *not* doing this on the event handling thread).
- You're synchronizing all access to whatever your `//do some stuff` code needs.
- You wrap everything after the `TryEnter` in a `try`/`finally`, like so:

.

```
public void MyEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Monitor.TryEnter(locker)) return;
    try
    {
        // do some stuff here
    }
    finally
    {
        Monitor.Exit(locker);
    }
}
```

It'd be nicer if you could prevent firing the event at all (and thus avoid starting a thread to potentially do nothing -- cause of course you're not doing this time-consuming processing on the event handling thread...)

Alternatively, if you don't really *need* to lock for the whole duration (that is, if the event handler won't be doing anything that requires synchronization with other code), you could lock just long enough to set a flag, like

```
private Object condition_lock = new Object();
private bool handlingEvent = false;

public void MyEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lock (condition_lock)
    {
        if (handlingEvent) return;
        handlingEvent = true;
    }
    try
    {
        // do some stuff here
    }
    finally
    {
        handlingEvent = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: good idea, because EventHandler is raised from background thread - I haven't realized that try - finally block should be used. I was wondering if I can do that this way. I'll test it. Preventing fireing event method is not possible directly, because eventhandler is called from proprietary DLL. But, can I remove it via -= MyEventHandler before Monitor.TryEnter and += after Monitor.Exit?

Comment: Conceivably, if you have a reference available there to the thing that's firing the event.  But you'd probably want to do that right *after* locking and *before* unlocking.  At that point, you can guarantee that (1) the current thread is the one handling the event (and thus the one responsible for restoring the event handler), and (2) the event handler is still there.  I'm assuming the chance of two simultaneous events is low, but even if it happens, it shouldn't cause issues as long as all of the event handling stuff (including removing/restoring the handler) is inside the critical section.

Comment: Problem is that I've find out that EvnetHandler is fired form the background thread very often and meanwhile it is processing its body, it is invoked again and causing problems. I don't want to do queuing of other events, or whatever else. I just want to skip them - so until processing of one event is finished, other events are not important for me.

Comment: That's not a problem, then.  Once you have the lock, remove the event handler's delegate.  Process the event, then re-add the delegate once you're done (in the `finally` block, just before you unlock).  Should keep the event handler from being called til you're done.  If you find you can't do that, though, then either example above will at least keep the event handler from running twice simultaneously.